# How do I query select all rows that match a value inside an array of objects inside a JSONB object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, postgresql, supabase

I have a database set up using Supabase. The name of the database is **sites**. Along with a few other columns, I have a JSONB column named **sitedata**.

Here is an example of the contents of the **sitedata** column.

```
{
  "status": true,
  "response": {
    "theme": {
      "desc": "Description",
      "name": "A theme name",
      "author": "An author",
      "version": "2.14.2",
      "isparent": "Yes"
    },
    "plugins": [
      {
        "desc": "AMP for WP - Accelerated Mobile Pages for WordPress",
        "name": "Accelerated Mobile Pages",
        "author": "Ahmed Kaludi, Mohammed Kaludi",
        "status": "Inactive",
        "update": "Yes",
        "version": "1.0.77.42",
        "new_version": "1.0.79"
      },
      {
        "desc": "Customize WordPress with powerful, professional and intuitive fields.",
        "name": "Advanced Custom Fields PRO",
        "author": "Delicious Brains",
        "status": "Active",
        "update": "No",
        "version": "5.12.3",
        "new_version": "-"
      },
      {
        "desc": "Used by millions, Akismet is quite possibly the best way in the world to <strong>protect your blog from spam</strong>. It keeps your site protected even while you sleep. To get started: activate the Akismet plugin and then go to your Akismet Settings page to set up your API key.",
        "name": "Akismet Anti-Spam",
        "author": "Automattic",
        "status": "Inactive",
        "update": "Yes",
        "version": "4.2.2",
        "new_version": "5.0.2"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I need to be able to fetch each row that shares the value of the key **name** inside the **sitedata.response.plugins** array of objects.

I have tried many things suggested by people through my Google searches, but nothing works. The last thing I tried was this, but it returns an empty array.

```
let { data, error } = await supabase.from('sites')
            .select('*')
            .contains("sitedata", {"response:jsonb->plugins": [{"name": "Accelerated Mobile Pages"}]});
```

Answer (score 1):

This ended up being what works.

```
let { data, error } = await supabase.from('sites')
.select('*') 
.not('lastupdated', 'is', null)
.contains('sitedata->response->plugins', JSON.stringify([{'name': 'Accelerated Mobile Pages'}]));
```